# How can I catch program calls

Tags: software-development, c++, monitoring, software-testing, system-monitor

lets imagine there is a software (.exe) Launch.exe which is written with C++. 
In other side there is one more software (.exe) which is Program.exe.

Thats how is works;
When run Launch.exe after a bit Program.exe starts like .bat command;
Program.exe code=5123 (<-- there is a random integer always created by Launch.exe) 
then Program.exe starts with version=2.5 parameter.
My question is; is there any way to catch it to see which parameters and values send from Launch.exe
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on Windows:

For an easy-to use freeware tool, try [Process Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor). If that does not help you, try [WinDbg's Logger.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847745/systrace-for-windows).

If you need more options, try the Google search ["strace windows"](https://www.google.com/search?q=strace+windows&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8s) and there are plenty of other hits.